# Run python subprocess for x seconds every y seconds

Tags: python, subprocess, sleep, wait

I'd like to control a bash program from within Python. I'd like to run an external command every x seconds for y seconds, and then kill it after y seconds. I'm having a bit of trouble with threads and sleep and wait and etc. and am wondering if someone can post a simple example.

For example, from the CLI the usage might be

```
./foo.py --runfor=10 --runevery=60
```

meaning `foo.py` would run something for 10 seconds every 60 seconds (not 60 seconds between). If it is off by a second or fractions of a second that is OK. I can do this by spawning a process that is blocking, and then doing some math to set the timer, but I think there might be a more elegant way with threads.

Comment: Try asking a specific question. An example of _what_? Threading? Spawning processes? Timing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

does this help?

```
import threading
import subprocess
import time

class IntervalRunner(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, seconds):
        self.seconds = seconds
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            p = subprocess.Popen('ls -la'.split(), shell=False,
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

            stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
            print stdout
            time.sleep(self.seconds)

runner = IntervalRunner(10)
runner.start()
runner.join()
```

Comment: It helps a bit. I clarified the question. I don't see how your code kills the p process after `y` seconds.

Comment: I'd do the loop like `while self.running:`.

Comment: OK I edited the answer to include `runfor` and `runevery` rather than just seconds. This appears to work for me. I hope editing your answer is acceptable. Thanks for getting me started down the right track.

Comment: Nope. My edit was not accepted. The example code only shows half the problem, and I'm not sure it shows that correctly. Nothing below `runner.join()` gets executed, so I'm not sure how this is threaded...

Comment: join make current thread wait for "runner" completion.. you need to create some variable on runner to count number of executions and then stop while loop.. at this point, runner thread will end and main thread will execute everything after `join`.. if you don't join your program will end before thread loop `runfor` times

Answer (score 0):

You can try the apscheduler module of python.It is similar to a cron-style scheduling.
http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/